# working with classes and ids

Tags: html, css, class, frontend

I will have to preface this question with that I am a relatively young and new developer.

I have five points with which I am trying to place them in specific areas around a page.  I know that with these five points I can create five specific classes, and then position each point to where I would like it. However I know that with using that method, it is not very dry. As a result I have tried incorporating one class, and having five ID's associated with the same class in an effort to shorten up the code a little bit.  However I ran into problems  going about it this way because I was unable to position the points to where I would have liked them to be.

My question is, is it possible to incorporate many ID's and have them associated with a class? If so, how would that be done?

This is the code that I am working with. The points end up side by side with each other, and not in the positions where I would like them to be. If a few people could take a gander at it, I would be very appreciative.  Much thanks in advance.

```
<div class = "box container">
<div class = "circle" id = "circle1"></div> 
<div class = "circle" id = "circle2"></div>
<div class = "circle" id = "circle3"></div>
<div class = "circle" id = "circle4"></div>
<div class = "circle" id = "circle5"></div>
</div>

.circle {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: red;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 50;
display: inline-block;
}


 #circle1{
left: 10em;
margin-top: 10em;
}

 #circle2{
left: 20em;
margin-top: 20em;
}

#circle3{
left: 30em;
top: 30em;
}

#circle4{
left: 40em;
top: 40em;
} 

#circle5{
left: 50em;
top: 50em;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to position the circles relative to the `box container` ? So `circle1` is within `box container` but has a space of `10em` at the left and top within the `box container` ?

Comment: I would look into [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), whether you want it if I were you, whether you want it to be relative, absolute, fixed etc.

Comment: You can have many classes on a single element: one common to all circles and one specific to each circle (instead of an id). There's a strong advice against using IDs for styling (in huge projects especially because specificity of selectors will bite you sooner or later) but it's NOT forbidden to use them for styling. And obviously do whatever you want in JS and do associate label (for attribute) with their form field (id attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `left` and `top` values will have no effect because you aren't giving your `.circle` class a `position`.

By default all elements have `position: static;`. Static elements can't be positioned with top, bottom, left or right

Add this to `.circle`:

`position: relative;`

Example:

```css
.circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}


 #circle1{
    left: 10em;
    margin-top: 10em;
}

 #circle2{
    left: 20em;
    margin-top: 20em;
}

#circle3{
    left: 30em;
    top: 30em;
}

#circle4{
    left: 40em;
    top: 40em;
} 

#circle5{
    left: 50em;
    top: 50em;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box container">
    <div class = "circle" id = "circle1"></div> 
    <div class = "circle" id = "circle2"></div>
    <div class = "circle" id = "circle3"></div>
    <div class = "circle" id = "circle4"></div>
    <div class = "circle" id = "circle5"></div>
</div>
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using id's at all here. They prevent you from using these styles elsewhere in the same document. You could just as easily use classes for all of your elements. See below...

Example.

```css
.circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}


.circle1{
    left: 10em;
    margin-top: 10em;
}

.circle2{
    left: 20em;
    margin-top: 20em;
}

.circle3{
    left: 30em;
    top: 30em;
}

.circle4{
    left: 40em;
    top: 40em;
} 

.circle5{
    left: 50em;
    top: 50em;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box container">
    <div class="circle circle1"></div> 
    <div class="circle circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle circle4"></div>
    <div class="circle circle5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I struggled with this for quite a while yesterday, and did not have anybody to ask for help.  I changed what you recommend, and it worked. Also thank you for the explanation regarding the default positioning of being static.

Comment: I also really like the thought of using purely classes. Putting two classes, or two elements inside of a div is a new thing I learned just yesterday, which I think is just awesome! Thanks again for everything!

Comment: @kdweber89 If this answered your question please remember to accept it so uʍopǝpısdn may get the credit for it.

Comment: Thanks @CalebB. Just took care of it.

Answer (score -1):

hmm I am not sure if I understand, but.. did you try with add .circle{position:fixed;} to your css ?

Comment: Answers are not the place for questions.

Comment: what do you mean? I provided him a solution position: fixed;

Comment: This solution may have been embedded in the question but if you want to answer his' question with this then phrase it like an answer. "hmm I am not sure if I understand, but.. did you try with add .circle{position:fixed;} to your css ?" is a question not a statement, an answer is a statement. You can edit your answer to be an answer but as it sits now it is a question.

Comment: I provided solution in jsfiddle. I asked if he tried my solution, not what he was asking about.

Comment: Then put that as your answer. Answers are not the place for questions, but for answers. If you need to place questions in your answer place them along with the answer not in place of the answer with an implied answer and a jsfiddle in the comments.